# Переменная становится undefined после возврата из функции

Tags: javascript

```
function getMax(arr, i = 1, max = arr[0]) {
    if (i == arr.length - 1) {
        console.log(max); // 123
        return max;
    } else {
        if (arr[i] > max)
            max = arr[i];

        getMax(arr, i + 1, max);
    }
}

const arr = [11, 12, 123, 3, 9, 12, 23, 100];
console.log(getMax(arr)); // undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function getMax(arr, i = 1, max = arr[0]) {
  if (i == arr.length) { // !!!
    return max;
  } else {
    if (arr[i] > max)
      max = arr[i];
    return getMax(arr, i + 1, max); // !!!
  }
}

const arr = [11, 12, 123, 3, 9, 12, 23, 100];
console.log(getMax(arr)); // defined
```